# Check if endpoint was called in python function

Tags: python, testing, python-behave

I'm writing behave tests for some python functions and in one test im trying to check
if a specific api endpoint was called properly.
The simplified Scenario would be:

```
  Scenario: Order was created properly
    When I order a product
    Then the order is forwarded to the tracker service
    And the order was placed successfully
```

And the steps file looks like this:

```py
@when("I order a product")
def ordering_product(context):
    context.order_id = order_product()

@then("the order is forwarded to the tracker service")
def forwarded_to_tracker(context):
    #need help here
    pass

@then("the order was placed successfully")
def successful_order(context):
    r = requests.get(f"http://order-api/orderstatus/{context.order_id}")
    data = r.json()
    assert data['status'] == 'SUCCESS'
```

and the order_product function:

```py
def order_product():
    my_order = create_order_body()
    requests.post("http://tracking-service/addorder", data=my_order)
    return requests.post("http://order-api/createorder", data=my_order)
```

My question is how can I check that the request to http://tracking-service was made without returning the response in addition to the order-api response from order_product.